# How to highlight dynamic property invocation in PhpStorm in a different color than?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

I like for my PhpStorm (version 8.0.3) to show potential errors and bugs in glaring colors in order to prevent time from being wasted.

Recently, I often discover myself doing this kind of typo:

```
$this->$someExistingProperty = 'fnord';
```

This obviously means something entirely different than:

```
$this->someExistingProperty = 'fnord';
```

Is it possible to configure PhpStorm that it shows dynamically invoked properties and methods in a different color, e.g. pink?

It also would help if only the `$` would appear in a different color, just like the semicolon.

Right now, I see it this way:

[image: Screenshot of current syntax highlighting]

Can I configure it and if so, where? I have searched through the Colors & Fonts tab for PHP but so far, without luck.

Comment: @LazyOne Current stable 8.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any options to highlight the line you want, but you can highlight the other identifier (in bold by example) in the Language Defaults or PHP menu:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: Facinating. The `Identifier` is the correct setting, yet the foreground color gets ignored. Making it bold is indeed a valid workaround.

Comment: @k0pernikus Maybe because that color/style gets overwritten later? Have you checked that possibility?

Comment: @LazyOne I assume so, yet it is hard to determine which font color overwrites which.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your editor color scheme.

This is what I see with my custom scheme (based on Default).

```
<?php
class TestClass
{
    protected $someVar;
    protected $anotherVar;

    public function ddd()
    {
        $someVar = 'anotherVar';

        $this->someVar = 123;
        $this->$someVar = 222;

    }
}

$z = new TestClass();
$z->ddd();
```

[image]

As you can see it's easy to tell what is what here.

**The styles are "Identifier" and "Variable".**

---

Although in general IDE should warn you about your `$this->$someExistingProperty` code -- because for that you have to have local `$someExistingProperty` variable defined...

This is what I see in v9 (note commented local `$someVar` line):

[image]

---

**P.S.**
In v9 (currently in EAP stage but will be released soon (within few weeks -- sometime in July))  few more styles were introduced, e.g. "Instance Field" which should allow you to differentiate between local variable and class property.